# showing error "uninitialized constant Spree::ProductTaxon" while updating spree_products_taxons table in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spree

I want to update `spree_products_taxons` table, but it is showing the error above. What am I am doing wrong?

```
def import_update

require 'csv'
file = params[:file]
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

@prod = Spree::Product.find(row["id"])
@var = Spree::Variant.find_by(product_id: @prod.id)

Spree::Product.where(:id => row["id"]).update_all(:name => row["name"], :meta_description => row["meta_description"], :shipping_category_id => row["shipping_category_id"], :description => row["description"], :meta_keywords => row["meta_keywords"], :tax_category_id => row["tax_category_id"], :available_on => row["available_on"], :deleted_at => row["deleted_at"], :promotionable => row["promotionable"], :meta_title => row["meta_title"], :featured => row["featured"], :supplier_id => row["supplier_id"])

Spree::Variant.find_by(id: @var.id).update(:cost_price => row["cost_price"], :depth => row["depth"], :height => row["height"], :width => row["width"], :weight => row["weight"], :tax_category_id => row["tax_category_id"], :is_master => row["is_master"], :position => row["position"], :cost_currency => row["cost_currency"], :deleted_at => row["deleted_at"], :track_inventory => row["track_inventory"], :tax_category_id => row["tax_category_id"])

Spree::Price.find_by(variant_id: @var.id).update(:amount => row["master_price"], :currency => row["cost_currency"], :deleted_at => row["deleted_at"])

Spree::ProductTaxon.find_by(product_id: @prod.id).update(:taxon_id => row["taxon_id"])

@prop = Spree::ProductProperty.find_by(product_id: @prod.id)
Spree::Property.find_by(id: @prop.property_id).update(:name => row["name"], :presentation => row["presentation"])
Spree::ProductProperty.find_by(product_id: @prod.id).update(value => row["value"])

stock_loc = Spree::StockLocation.find_by(supplier_id: @prod.supplier_id)
Spree::StockItem.where(:variant_id => @variants.id, :stock_location_id => stock_loc.id).update_all(:count_on_hand => row["count_on_hand"], :backorderable => row["backorderable"])

end

redirect_to admin_products_path, notice: "Products Updated."

end
```

Comment: Post you error log and related code

Answer (score 2):

Although the table is called spree_products_taxons (see schema.rb) for some reason the model is Spree::Classification.

Answer (score 0):

You table is `spree_products_taxons` so it's expecting `Spree::ProductsTaxon` (mind that its `Products` NOT `Product`) model class. Make sure your model should be named as Spree::ProductsTaxon

I can see you are using `Spree::ProductTaxon` in your code. Please update and try.

Hope it helps.

Comment: no, It is not working.Again showing showing same error."NameError in Spree::Admin::ProductsController#import_update" and 
 "uninitialized constant Spree::ProductsTaxon"

Comment: What is your model name? It should be `Spree::ProductsTaxon`

Comment: No direct models are present as I am using spree gem. These models are within gem file. One is product.rb and another taxon.rb . Then how to update that???

Comment: Post link to your tutorial. Your model names don't map with table name

Comment: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product.rb   https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product.rb/taxon.rb                                                                                                            I am using spree gem